# Where to ask about slow AJAX calls

Tags: support, site-recommendation, ajax, server

I have been just banging my head against the wall on an issue I'm having regarding one of my intranet sites, and why the AJAX calls are slow, once the site is added to one of our servers.

I will have some details to show, and it may come down to server configuration, as I don't think anything is wrong with my code.

Comment: Questions about problems you are having with code go on Stack Overflow, if you can provide enough relevant detail to make them answerable.  I'll leave it to the ServerFault guys to decide whether or not it would be on-topic there.

Comment: Worth noting: you can get a fair idea what kinds of questions will be acceptable on a particular site by reviewing their Help Center, looking at well-received questions on their front page, and looking at their Meta site.  If you're still not sure, you can try asking in their chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're certain it's not your code, then it comes down to an issue on your webserver, which gives you two options:

[ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) or [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Sounds like it might be a fit on either site, so take your pick.